# Difference in timing while getting values from ROM or RAM

Tags: process, vhdl, fpga, ram, rom

So I am having a hard time understanding the time it takes to get values from ram or rom in vhdl. To insert data into ram I know happens on the rising edge of the clock and takes one clock such as the example I have, but in terms of getting data out does it take one clock to get the data from memory and then get then another clock cycle to get the data to output meaning it takes 2 clock cycles to get data?

```
 process(clk)
 begin
 if(rising_edge(clk)) then
    if(write_en = '1') then
       mem(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= incoming_data;--insert data
    end if;
 end if;
end process;
out_data <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(address))); -- takes 2 clock cycles to get data ?
```

Comment: The functionality you are trying to implement appears to be a "Read old; Write new" RAM, except you are trying to perform an asynchronous read (not sure why). I would move the `out_data` assignment, such that it is within the clk'd process (and thus, sync). This will result in a RAM that writes a value to the specified address in `mem`, and also reads the old value for the specified address; The output would be available on the next clock cycle. Some good info [here](https://www.altera.co.jp/ja_JP/pdfs/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii51007.pdf)

Comment: This is insufficient code to detect and explain the cause of the issue. Please post a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

No, it takes 1 clock cycle:

In your code you have two concurrent processes. One is explicit:

```
process(clk)
begin
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then
    if(write_en = '1') then
      mem(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= incoming_data;--insert data
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

The other is implicit; it is a *concurrent signal assignment*:

```
out_data <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(address))); -- takes 2 clock cycles to get data ?
```

The concurrent signal assignment is exactly equivalent to this:

```
process(address, mem)
begin
  out_data <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(address))); -- takes 2 clock cycles to get data ?
end process;
```

In other words, it is equivalent to a process with `address` and `mem` in the sensitivity list. Any concurrent signal assignment is equivalent to a process with all the inputs in the sensitivity list. An input to a concurrent signal assignment is any signal on the right hand side of the signal assignment operator (`<=`). So, you get a sensitivity list for free and that is an advantage of using concurrent signal assignments: you cannot accidentally miss out a signal from the sensitivity list, because the compiler creates it for you.

So, lets consider what happens when each process is executed. The first process has just the signal `clk` in its sensitivity list, so the process executes whenever there is a change (an *event*) on `clk`. If this change is not a rising edge then the `rising_edge` function returns `FALSE` and the process immediately suspends. If this change is a rising edge then the `rising_edge` function returns `TRUE` and if the expression `write_en = '1'` is also `TRUE` then this line gets executed:

```
mem(to_integer(unsigned(address))) <= incoming_data;--insert data
```

The effect of this line is to put an event on the *event queue* to drive the correct value of `mem` on the next *delta cycle* (assuming there is some change to the signal `mem` as a result). The event queue is the simulator's "to do" list; a delta cycle is one iteration of the simulator; the next iteration will occur once all the processes that are executing in the current iteration suspend.

So, the next iteration cycle occurs and the signal `mem` gets its new value. The signal `mem` is in the implicit sensitivity list of the second (implicit) process (the concurrent signal assignment). So, this second process starts executing and the line with the signal assignment to `out_data` is executed and (as with the executing of any line containing a signal assignment) an event is put on the event queue to drive the target signal - `out_data` in this case - to a new value (again assuming the value should change).

So, the change to the signal `out_data` always occurs one delta cycle after a change on the signal `mem`. We've already established that the signal `mem` changes one delta cycle after any rising edge on the signal `clk`, so we can see that the signal `out_data` changes two delta cycles after any rising edge on the signal `clk`.

Whilst it is vital to be aware of delta cycles when writing VHDL, we don't usually need to worry about them if we adopt a good, conventional style. So, we can just say that the signal `out_data` changes on any rising edge of the signal `clk` or, in other words, **there is a delay of one clock cycle between any changes on the signals `write_en`, `incoming_data` or `address` and any corresponding change on the signal `out_data`**.

Comment: Great explanation, so now lets assume that we put that out_data expression as follow:

Comment: Excuse my error above, I accidentally posted before I finished. Great explanation, so now lets assume that we put that "out_data" signal assignment after the second if statement inside the process. Now if rising_edge is true and write_en = '1' the signal assignment to mem would cause one event and the signal assignment to out_data would cause another event meaning 2 events on the same iteration? I guess I am just thinking way to deeply about delta cycles lately when ultimately I just wanted to know is whether out_data gets its value on the same rising clock that mem gets assigned.

Comment: If you put that `out_data` signal assignment after the second if statement inside the process, then the delay between `incoming_data` and `out_data` would be two clock cycles. As each line containing a signal assignment is executed, the right hand side would be sampled and an event put on the event queue to drive the left hand side to that value. **Both assignments would be executed in the same delta cycle. Therefore both right hand sides would be sampled in the same delta cycle. Therefore, any change on `incoming_data` would take two iterations _of the process_ to affect `out data`.**